# How to loop glm

Tags: r, machine-learning, glmnet

I want to loop ridge & lasso for 100 times to get 100 mse and mspe. My final goal is draw a boxplot to compare those 100 values.  I made one regression model but I don't know how to repeat this model.
How could I get the values and boxplots?

Comment: I think my question is incomplete. but i just wanna know how to loop this model , not specific codes.

Comment: What's your `betas.true`?

Comment: betas.true=c(rep(0.5, 10),rep(0,P-10))    and p=50

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
ntimes <- 100

res <- replicate(ntimes, {
  cv.rr <- cv.glmnet(x=as.matrix(train[,-1]),y=as.numeric(train[,1]),alpha=0,nfolds=10,nlambda=100, intercept=FALSE)
  
  lambda.rr=cv.rr$lambda.min      
  mse.rr <- mean((coef(cv.rr)[-1] - betas.true)^2)    
  yhat.rr <- predict(cv.rr,s="lambda.min",newx=as.matrix(test[,-1]))
  mspe.rr <- mean((test[,1]-yhat.rr)^2)
  
  list(mse=mse.rr, mspe=mspe.rr)  
})

library(tidyverse)
res_df <- as.data.frame(apply(res, 1, function(x) unlist(x)))
names(res_df) <- c('mse', 'mspe')
res_df %>% gather(key='metric', value='value') %>% ggplot(aes(value, fill=metric)) + geom_boxplot()
```

to obtain a visualization like the following:

[image]